# How big is all of debian buster for amd64?

Tags: debian, repository

I can get the size of the debian archive from https://www.debian.org/mirror/size.

Is there a way to get the size of **only Debian Buster for amd64**? And separately for `main`, `contrib` and `non-free`?

Comment: Are you interested in the size of the archive or the size of an installation?  If the latter, what kind of installation are you interested in?  Desktop environments take up a lot more space than a small server install.

Comment: I am interested in the size before installation and I am not sure which packages I might need.